# AngularJs filtering using three filters but only two of the three work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a json file with book information and a web page where one filter filters by Author, Title and year read and is working. Another filter filters by Booktype and is working. A third filter filters by rating but is not working. If I add the third filter to the ng-repeat no data at all displays. I have an example on Plunker. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

https://embed.plnkr.co/x8hDq8VizRrZRS7vDQq3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in function `chooseRating` in `Book_module.js`. You wrote `$scope.RatingFilter.five`, `$scope.RatingFilter.four`... while they should be `$scope.Filter.RatingFilter.five` and so on.